# Do we need EN in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Here is an example sentence taken from a coursebook

> *Je m'en vais chez moi, pour me coucher.*

And here is a recommendation I've found online: *Ne dites jamais*

> Je m'en vais à la maison...

Il faut simplement dire

> Je vais à la maison *ou* Je m'en vais.

Since these two pieces of advice are mutually exclusive, could anyone comment on them? Which of them should learners of French ignore?

Comment: The second advice is correct. In the first sentence, "s'en aller" should be replaced by "partir" : *je pars chez moi pour me coucher*.

Comment: Thank you, Graffito. But why is it used so often? Is it acceptable in certain dialects, e.g. Canadian? Here a few examples I have managed to find:  Je m’en vais chez elle lui offrir un petit cadeau et je lui ai même confectionné une carte. Angie, on a du travail ce soir, moi et Manuel —— Je m’en vais chez lui.... Bye bye Boss, je m’en vais chez le concurrent. Tous les samedis, je m'en vais chez mon oncle.

Comment: Strictly speaking  we should use *s'en aller* only if we do not mention where to, *Je m'en irai/partirai à 7 heures* but *Je partirai chez moi à 7 heures*.  But in colloquial speech lots of people use *s'en aller* followed by the location, hence all the examples you have found. Consider that (cf your comment), *chez le concurrent* is not necessarily  a physical location but can be understood as the organisation (although *chez la concurrence* would be preferred).

Answer (score 7):

***Ne dites jamais*** is excessively prescriptive, if not plain wrong.

The fact is this ***je m'en vais à la maison*** is often said by native people and many wouldn't even suspect there might be an issue with that sentence.

***S'en aller*** is a set expression meaning to leave (or to be about to do sth), ***en*** no more refers to anything analyzable so there is no compelling reason to forbid telling to where you leave.

Paul Verlaine hadn't trouble writing:

> *Et je m’en vais
>
> Au vent mauvais
>
> Qui m’emporte
>
> Deçà, delà,
>
> Pareil à la
>
> Feuille morte.*

Nor Molière:

> *Je m'en vais cependant au logis comme si de rien n'était.*

Alexandre Dumas (père):

> *Enfin, le voici... je m'en vais à la Bibliothèque... dix heures et demie... c'est effrayant.*

Alexandre Dumas (fils):

> *[...] adieu, alors, bonsoir; il ne me suffit plus votre théâtre, elle ne me suffit plus, votre gloire; je m'en vais à la campagne; j'achète un lopin de terre avec ce que m'a donné l'éternel mariage d'Arthur et d'Henriette, et je vais planter des choux.*

Reciprocally, nobody complain about the fact we can say:

> Je m'en vais d'ici.

Comment: Yet another false prescription :-)

Comment: I'd like to thank everybody for the comments!

Comment: I would add, at least to me, it seems "je m'en vais à la bibliothèque" shifts the emphasis to the moment where the going starts rather than where it ends.